# Jquery - creating a function and passing a document element as an argument to it

Tags: jquery, hover

I have an element with id `#contactblurb` defined in HTML:

```
<div id="contactblurb" class="tab">
  email:  info@something.co.uk
</div>
```

And when the mouse hovers over another element (`#contactNav`), I want to hide some other elements and show this `#contactblurb`. I want to be able to do this with other elements, not just `#contactblurb`, so I created a function in jquery that takes ( what i thought was ) the element to hide:

```
var HideSlidesAndShowMe = function($elem)
{
  $('#slides').fadeOut('slow', function()
  { 
    $('#acorn').css({opacity : 0.05});

    $elem.show();
  });
}
```

I'm calling it via:

```
$("#contactNav").hover( function () {
                                   HideSlidesAndShowMe($("#contactblurb")) ;
                                 },
                                 function () 
                                 {
                                   // other stuff on exit hover.
                                 }
                    );
```

But it doesn't show #contactblurb, it does do the other stuff however.

Is there something wrong with the way I'm passing the argument?

Comment: The way you are passing it is correct. Look here: http://jsfiddle.net/techfoobar/8FH46/

Comment: That's strange, I could only get it to work by removing the `$` in front of the `elem`, in the function declaration.

Comment: `$elem` is as valid an identifier name as `elem`. It should work both ways!

Comment: @techfoobar indeed it should work fine, set this as post I will +1 you bruv `:)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/g9kBC/

This seems to be behaving fine check your html again and the closing brackets even with `$` sign it should behave `:)`

**code**

```
var HideSlidesAndShowMe = function($elem) {
    //$('#slides').fadeOut('slow', function() {
      //  $('#acorn').css({
        //    opacity: 0.05
        //});
       alert($elem.attr('id'));
        $elem.show();
    }


$("#contactNav").hover(function() {
    alert('f');
    HideSlidesAndShowMe($("#contactblurb"));
}, function() {
    // other stuff on exit hover.
});​
```